# titanium appcelerator query is slow

Tags: sqlite, indexing, titanium

i have a titanium appcelerator query that looks like this:

```
"select * from module where language_id = " + languageId + " order by id asc";
```

When i run this query on my android-powered titanium app, when the number of entries for the given language_id is low (say, 5) then this query returns quickly.

When the number of entries is higher - say 100 - then this query takes a lot longer (say a second longer).

I've used an index on the table like so:

```
CREATE INDEX "module_index" ON "module" ("language_id" ASC)
```

I created this index on the table using the firefox sqlite browser. The app definitely knows the index exists, because if in the code I run

```
db.execute("CREATE INDEX 'module_index' ON 'module' ('language_id' ASC)");
```

I get an error saying that the index already exists. I also tried running

```
db.execute("REINDEX 'main'.'module_index'");
```

But that doesn't seem to alleviate the issue.

What is the issue here - I was assuming that an indexed table on a nexus 4 would be able to retrieve 100 or so results pretty quickly, but this doesn't appear to be the case. Is my indexing incorrect, or am i missing something?

Comment: For what code do you measure the time? How much data is there?

Comment: I'm not using code to measure the time - I press a button on my app and can see how long it takes to respond. Removing the sql "get" makes the code instantaneous, and responses for results of larger queries take longer. The overall size of the table is about 500 rows, but my query for 100 items takes about two seconds, which seems off to me.

Comment: The slow part is likely to be your code that does something with the records.

Comment: How dare you insinuate my code is sloppy! Here, let me do some checks to... prove... oh, my, um...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This doesn't really solve my question - because in the end, as CL points out, it was the code that was making a list of the entries that was the issue.

Titanium's TableView isn't very performant. I've since [switched to using ListView.](http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/3.0/#!/guide/ListViews) This is much faster, and resolved my issues.